# MDX query to sum measure of items containing dimension member

Tags: mdx, olap, olap-cube, mondrian, rolap

This MDX query:

```
WITH
MEMBER [Measures].[# answered] AS
    ([Dispozice].[Dispozice].[ANSWERED], [Measures].[# hovorů])
SELECT
{[Measures].[# hovorů], [Measures].[# answered]} ON COLUMNS,
CrossJoin([Datum vytvoření.Po dnech].[Rok].[2017], [Dispozice].[Dispozice].Members) ON ROWS
FROM [Hovory]
```

returns this table:

[image]

but I need something like this:

[image]

I need to sum measure `# hovorů` only for those items that has the `ANSWERED` member of dimension `Dispozice`. I want to add this as computed measurement which will be used to calculate percantage.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried: (existing [Dispozice].[Dispozice].[ANSWERED], [Measures].[# hovorů]) ? I'm not sure if it's supported by Mondrian.

Comment: @DanyloKorostil There is no existing keyword in mondrian :( ... do you have any suggestions to work around this?

Comment: I thought it was supported: http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/MONDRIAN-1180

Comment: Can you change the cube structure?

Comment: Yea, I did. It was the easiest way. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing just using `iif` with a `null` branch is too much hard coding:

```
WITH
MEMBER [Measures].[# answered] AS
    iif(
      [Dispozice].CURRENTMEMBER IS [Dispozice].[Dispozice].[ANSWERED]
    , [Measures].[# hovorů]
    , NULL
    )
```

Comment: Yea it is possibility, but this way `[Duspozice]` dimension has to be present in the query. 

WITH
MEMBER [Measures].[# answered] AS
    iif(
      [Dispozice].CURRENTMEMBER IS [Dispozice].[Dispozice].[ANSWERED]
    , [Measures].[# hovorů]
    , NULL
    )
SELECT
{[Measures].[# hovorů], [Measures].[# answered]} ON COLUMNS,
[Datum vytvoření.Po dnech].[Rok].Members ON ROWS
FROM [Hovory]

Will return NULL.

Comment: @JakubTruneček is NonEmpty implemented within the Mondrian dialect?

Comment: IIF([Dispozice].CurrentMember is [Dispozice].[Dispozice].[All], ([Dispozice].[Dispozice].[ANSWERED],[Measures].[# hovorů]),NULL) also may be a way to go. I mean, rewrite that with the case statement. However, it's too dirty to debug in the future. So, without the existing keyword you have to filter answers on the DWH.